# Nested categories counting only one branch with products

Tags: mysql, nested

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site_location` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

///DATA
    INSERT INTO `site_location` (`id`, `level`, `lft`, `rgt`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 0, 1, 24, 'United Kingdom'),
    (2, 1, 2, 19, 'London'),
    (3, 2, 13, 14, 'Central London'),
    (4, 2, 11, 12, 'East London'),
    (5, 2, 9, 10, 'North London'),
    (6, 2, 7, 8, 'North West London'),
    (7, 2, 5, 6, 'South East London'),
    (8, 2, 3, 4, 'West London'),
    (9, 2, 15, 18, 'South West'),
    (10, 3, 16, 17, 'Battersea'),
    (11, 1, 20, 23, 'Brighton'),
    (12, 2, 21, 22, 'Guildford');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ads` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `ads` (`id`, `category_id`, `location`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 7, 10, 'Test1'),
(2, 9, 3, 'Test2'),
(3, 12, 10, 'Test3'),
(4, 13, 4, 'Test4');
```

when ID is ID=1 to return this way

```
[ United Kingdom(4) ]
    London(4)     
    Brighton(0)
```

and when ID is ID = 2

```
    United Kingdom(4)
      [ London(4) ]
        South West(2)
        Central London(1)
        East London(1)
      Brighton(0)
```

so when is selected "London" I need all its siblings and all its children

the same when is selected "South West" I need all its siblings all its children, its parent all its parent siblings

```
    United Kingdom(4)
      London(4)
        [ South West(2) ]
          Battersea(2)
        Central London(1)
        East London(1)
      Brighton(0)
```

and as well how many ads have in the location, for example in UK has to have 4 because all ads in the table are 4, south west has to have 2 because in Battersea has 2

when id is 11

```
United Kingdom(4)
  London(4)
  [ Brighton(0) ]
      Guildford(0)
```

I have a query:
 South West lft:15, rgt:18, level:2

```
 SELECT 
    node.id, 
    node.alias, 
    node.level, 
    node.name, 
    COUNT(ads.id) as ads,
    IF(node.lft = node.rgt-1, "0", "1") AS `has_children`
 FROM 
    site_location AS parent LEFT JOIN
    ads as ads ON (parent.id = ads.location),
    site_location AS node
 WHERE
    parent.lft BETWEEN node.lft AND node.rgt
 AND 
    parent.lft BETWEEN 15 AND 18
 AND 
    node.level > 0
 AND
   node.level < 2 + 3
 GROUP BY node.id
 ORDER BY node.lft
```

this will return

```
 London(4)
  South West(2)
   Battersea(2)
```

I need to be in this way

```
 London(4)
  South West(2)
   Battersea(2)
 Brighton(0)
```

Is it possible to do this with single query :?
If anyone can help, It will be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you give more info about your schema or (even better) post a sqlfiddle?

Comment: @caitriona I gave more info if you can help me. Thanks in advance.